# python iterating over a list of lists

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I have:

```
master_list = [['001', '15\n', '963789', '40\n', '741239', '80\n', '985697', '80\n', '854698', '35\n', '965874', '10\n'],
 ['002', '25\n', '326574', '65\n', '944223', '40\n', '312689', '45\n', '225869', '80\n', '789654', '35\n'],
 ['003', '10\n', '857963', '50\n', '253698', '40\n', '965478', '50\n', '186458', '40\n', '351296', '40\n'],
 ['004', '20\n', '675964', '40\n', '612985', '40\n', '653674', '35\n', '957296', '50\n', '852169', '40\n'],
 ['005', '13', '246912', '40\n', '371956', '40\n', '819736', '40\n', '915745', '50\n', '197548', '40']]
```

the first two items of the inner list are an id and a pay rate. as in master[0][0], master[0][1]

i then have:

```
for row in master_list:
        emp_id = row.pop(0)# extracts the employee id
        hourly_rate = row.pop(0)# extracts the hourly rate
```

the `row` then becomes something like this:
`['963789', '40\n', '741239', '80\n', '985697', '80\n', '854698', '35\n', '965874', '10\n']`

the first item in this row is a job number and the second item is hours worked. the third item is a job number and the fourth item is hours worked etc. until the end of the list...

How would I iterate this list to print something like:

```
Job Number: 963789
Employee ID: 001
Hours Worker: 40
Hourly Rate: 15

Job Number: 741239
Employee ID: 001
Hours Worker: 80
Hourly Rate: 15
```

etc...

Answer (score 2):

For each row you can access the data like so

```
job_number = row[::2]
hours_worked = row[1::2]
```

To print, just do something like this

```
for row in master_list:
    emp_id = row.pop(0)# extracts the employee id
    hourly_rate = row.pop(0)# extracts the hourly rate
    job_number = row[::2]
    hours_worked = row[1::2]
    for i in range(len(job_number)):
        print "Job Number: {jn}\nEmployee ID: {eid}\nHours Worked: {hrw}\nHourly Rate: {hrr}\n".format(jn=rob_number[i], eid=emp_id, hrw=hours_worked[i], hrr=hourly_rate)
```

Comment: I got the same idea but you were faster :)

Comment: What are all the {} for?

Comment: @robertrocha its for the `"".format()` to work - it finds the `{}` and replaces them with the appropriate string

Comment: @robertrocha Those are python string format specifiers - https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#format-string-syntax

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to go about it (explanations in the code comments):

```
titles = ['Employee ID', 'Hourly Rate', 'Job Number', 'Hours Worker'] #assuming these are the only titles you are interested in
master_list = [['001', '15\n', '963789', '40\n', '741239', '80\n', '985697', '80\n', '854698', '35\n', '965874', '10\n'],
 ['002', '25\n', '326574', '65\n', '944223', '40\n', '312689', '45\n', '225869', '80\n', '789654', '35\n'],
 ['003', '10\n', '857963', '50\n', '253698', '40\n', '965478', '50\n', '186458', '40\n', '351296', '40\n'],
 ['004', '20\n', '675964', '40\n', '612985', '40\n', '653674', '35\n', '957296', '50\n', '852169', '40\n'],
 ['005', '13', '246912', '40\n', '371956', '40\n', '819736', '40\n', '915745', '50\n', '197548', '40']]

new_master_list = [a_list[:4] for a_list in master_list] #since you are only interested in first 4 items in a sub list

for a_list in new_master_list:
    for item in a_list:
        print('{}: {}'.format(titles[a_list.index(item)], item.strip()))
    print() # for the new line after every sub list
```

This gives:

```
Employee ID: 001
Hourly Rate: 15
Job Number: 963789
Hours Worker: 40

Employee ID: 002
Hourly Rate: 25
Job Number: 326574
Hours Worker: 65

Employee ID: 003
Hourly Rate: 10
Job Number: 857963
Hours Worker: 50

Employee ID: 004
Hourly Rate: 20
Job Number: 675964
Hours Worker: 40

Employee ID: 005
Hourly Rate: 13
Job Number: 246912
Hours Worker: 40
```

The list `titles` is just for printing purposes. When iterating over the elements of the inner list (`a_list`, which is the same as `row` in yours), the code picks the corresponding element from the `titles` list by doing `titles[a_list.index(item)]` and prints them together.

Documentation on the python string formatting specifier `{}` [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#format-string-syntax). The line:

```
[a_list[:4] for a_list in master_list]
```

is a list comprehension. More on it [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: Where is a_list? I am new to list syntax in python

Comment: Thanks but this solution is too advanced for me